# Mongoose- How to reference embed document element?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have users.js schema with a embeded document array pets. For each user, a user can have multiple pets(usually no more than 3 I would think).

For each pet, there would be a daily chart. So it would be many daily charts for a pet. I have read with embedded documents that each array element is indexed. In daily.js, how can I reference the pet it would belong to for the populate() function?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    lastName: { type: String, required: true },
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    location: String,
    pets: [{ name: 'string', animalType: 'string'}], //could have more than one pet
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date
});
```

---

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var dailySchema = new Schema({
  tite: String,
  _pet: { type: Number, ref: 'User.pet' }, // not sure how to reference name in user.pets[#] array
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Quoting](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2772#issuecomment-83573381)

> Sorry to disappoint but that is an anti-pattern. Populate can't populate from another collection's subdocs - the reason why you're getting that error is that there's no model for boards.

So it may be not good patten to reference to embedded document. It could be better to separate `pet` from `User` as one schema

```
var PetSchema = new Schema ({ 
    name: 'string', 
    animalType: 'string'
});
```

And the `UserSchema` and `DailySchema` will be

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    pets: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Pet' }], //could have more than one pet
});

var dailySchema = new Schema({
  _pet: { type: Number, ref: 'Pet' }, // not sure how to reference name in user.pets[#] array
});
```

Comment: ah....thanks. this clears up alot for a newbie like me. What is the diff between `type: Schema.Types.ObjectId` and `type: Number` in this context? I've read about it in mongoose docs populate but still don't quite understand.

Comment: @dman, I think both of them are same, becasue `ObjectId, Number, String, and Buffer are valid for use as refs`.